# MdiParentForm is a type and can't be used as an expression error in Visual Basic 2013

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I created a new project with default form in it. I named the form as `mdiparentform`, set its `isMdiContainer` property to true. inserted another form. I called it on Mdi Form load as follows -

```
Dim Home As New Home()
Home.MdiParent = Me
Home.Show()
```

So far, everything is working correctly.
Then, I inserted a button in this form `Home` and tried to show another form as a child form, from this.

```
Dim settings As New settings()
settings.MdiParent = mdiparentform
settings.Show()
```

But this code is not even compiling. It shows a red line below `mdiparentform` and throw this error
`'mdiparentform' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.`

I am confused why is this error occurring and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i just found the blunder. There was a **Form Name** (the one which is shown in Property window, when we select the form) and **Form File Name** (the one with .VB extension) mismatch.

p.s. - Although it's newbie's (like me) mistake. But posting answer to my own question, because I thought it might be helpful for future searches to this error.